# Rename files to order them using perl substitution

Tags: regular-expression, rename

I have a set of files like the following

```
fine_0.vtu
fine_10.vtu
fine_4032.vtu
...
```

I want to add padding 0s to be able to order them and render them

I am trying this command

```
rename -n 's/fine_(\d+).vtu/sprintf("%05d", $1)/e' fine*.vtu
```

but it's not showing anything. How should I modify the command to see the new namings and then apply it?

Comment: Which `rename` are you using? As roaima points out in an answer below, there are many programs called `rename` and they behave quite differently. If you don't know, please at least tell us what operating system you are using since that will help us guess which `rename` you are likely to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the version of `rename` that you have. Here's what my version reports:

```
rename
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]
```

Please be aware, though, that the [default `rename` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) on many systems is the version from the `util-linux` package, which is not the `perl` one.

However, assuming you do have the `perl` version of `rename` (sometimes called `prename`), here's a worked example:

```
$ touch  fine_{0..99}.vtu

$ ls
fine_0.vtu   fine_24.vtu  fine_4.vtu   fine_55.vtu  fine_70.vtu fine_86.vtu
fine_1.vtu   fine_25.vtu  fine_40.vtu  fine_56.vtu  fine_71.vtu  fine_87.vtu
fine_10.vtu  fine_26.vtu  fine_41.vtu  fine_57.vtu  fine_72.vtu  fine_88.vtu
...          ...          ...          ...          ...

$ rename -n 's/^(.*_)(\d+)(\..*)/sprintf "%s%05d%s", $1, $2, $3/e' fine*
fine_0.vtu renamed as fine_00000.vtu
fine_1.vtu renamed as fine_00001.vtu
fine_10.vtu renamed as fine_00010.vtu
fine_11.vtu renamed as fine_00011.vtu
...

$ rm fine_{0..99}.vtu    # or: rm fine_?????.vtu
```

Remember either to remove `-n` or replace it with `-v` to allow the tool to affect the selected files.

After all that, if you don't have `[p]rename` you can reimplement a version of it in `perl` straightforwardly

```
perl -MFile::Copy -e '
    foreach $f (@ARGV) {
        ($t = $f) =~ s/^(.*_)(\d+)(\..*)/sprintf "%s%05d%s", $1, $2, $3/e;
        warn sprintf("%s -> %s\n", $f, $t);
        move($f, $t);
    }
' fine_*
```

Comment: Yeah, completely depends on rename version. I have installed perl-rename package in archlinux and my command worked fine! Thanks for all the information and the perl script bonus

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` instead:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
```

to autoload the `zmv` function (best in `~/.zshrc`).

Then:

```
zmv -n '(fine_)(<->)(.vtu)' '$1${(l[5][0])2}$3'
```

(`-n` for dry-run).